# How to unlock toolbars in Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)

Tags: eclipse, toolbar, eclipse-juno

I migrated from Eclipse Indigo (3.7) to Juno (4.2). In Juno all toolbars seem to be permanently locked. Is there a way to unlock them so they could be moved or rearranged?

Comment: As it turned out the ability to move toolbars (or any trim elements for that matter) is broken in Eclipse Juno. Here's a direct link to the **[Bug #340695](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340695)** for everyone who's interested in tracking this issue.

Comment: +1 Why is this a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: use the windows7 theme. the other themes cause some actual performance issues. toolbar keeps re-rendering too

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*I posted this earlier as a comment to my question, but was suggested that it should be an answer, so here we go:*

It has been **officially confirmed** that the ability to move toolbars (or any trim elements for that matter) is **broken** in Eclipse Juno. Here's the link to the [**Bug #340695**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340695) for everyone who's interested in tracking this issue. The fix is expected in the Milestone release 4.2.2.

Comment: You would have thoughts things like this are pretty difficult to get wrong in 2012.

Comment: So much for using the latest eclipse! #facepalm

Answer (score 39):

Try 
Windows- Preferences - Appearance

See the print:

[image]

Then type Theme in the Search box (or go General->Appeearance->Theme) and choose Window 7. restart and you'll be able to move the icons/groups in the toolbar (but not get rid of any)

After you're done you'll be asked to restart/ I went to Classsic theme and THEN restarted.

Hope it helps

Comment: Theme dropdown is empty in my installation of Eclipse (Android Developer Tools based on Eclipse 4.2.1).

Comment: This was the fix for Kepler on Windows 8.

Comment: This was also the fix for Kepler on Windows 7.

Comment: That's great, in linux, you can change to theme "Classic"

Comment: This was also the fix for Luna on Windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: Also works on Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1), Win 8.1 x64. Many thanks!

Comment: Works for Spring Source Toolkit as well on Win 10 Preview. Thanks, that was super distracting having huge empty spaces on the toolbar.

Answer (score 7):

Changing the theme to Windows 7 work fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that this is possible today.

Answer (score 4):

Partial workaround: http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2012/07/hide_eclipse_juno_toolbar.html

Use Help > Welcome, then Window / Show Toolbar. At that point you should be able to move your minimized window toolbar(s) around (what was "fast view" before).

Answer (score 2):

Good grief. I tried changing to the Windows 7 Classic theme because I was unable to move my toolbar buttons. Worse even, when the debug perspective opened automatically upon hitting the first breakpoint, the Java perspective button remained pressed, but pressing it again changed back to the Java perspective. Now, with Windows 7 Classic, the editor tabs look like in Indigo (whose look&feel personally I liked much better), but now the menu bar is gone and all perspective chooser buttons are gone too. The menu hotkeys (such as "Alt-W p" to get to Window-Preferences) don't seem to work. If I don't want to re-install I would probably now have to fiddle with some config files to find the Theme setting. Well, thank you...

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse Kepler, I have [reported the bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421539) again (the fix to the previously listed bug doesn't appear to have made a difference), and listed a workaround.

Changing the CSS for the org.eclipse.platform plugin to use `../images/` instead of `./` in all of the image URLs should cause it to start working.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is still broken in v4.3/Kepler. Thanks to the above appends I found a way to fix this (using theme Windows Classic).

Thanks folks!
M.