# how to unlock toolbar in Eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

Eclipse Luna Help says to "unlock the toolbar by right clicking the toolbar and selecting the Lock the Toolbars menu item." However, when I right click the toolbar, no options at all are displayed. Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure why it doesn't show up in the right click menu as the documentation suggests, but you can access the *Lock the Toolbars* command from quick access menu (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>).

However that doesn't seem to have any effect and there is and [open bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409633) for that, so this functionality is probably currently broken.

Comment: Appears so. Added a comment to that bug report to include this missing functionality.

Comment: thanks for confirming that this is broken.  The funny thing is my first try to figure out my problem lead to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301795/how-to-unlock-toolbars-in-eclipse-4-2-juno  eclipse likes breaking it's toolbars apparently :)

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the 'Theme' and 'Color and Font theme' are not selected in *Window - Preferences - General - Appearance*. See the print:

[image]

After selecting them and restarted Eclipse, The toolbars are unlocked.

Comment: After everything else didn't work I just had to try this and this worked for me! After restarting Eclipse the toolbar was unlocked and I was able to re-arrange the icons.